# Which UML tool can really round-trip java code?

Tags: uml, state-machine, roundtrip

Many UML tools claim to do forward / reverse engineering of Java code. However, it turns out from prior experience, that few tools really work in this area.

I haven't been doing Java projects for 3 years, and want to get up to date with the current status in this area.

In Particular I am interested in Creating State Machine Skeletons from Diagram, be able to create hooks to my own code, and be able to reverse engineer the State Diagram back (Do not want to change the State Machine itself outside the Tool).

Which UML tools works in this area? Enterprise Architecht? Visual Paradigm? Others?

Geir Ove
Norway

Answer (score 0):

The reverse engineering from code to UML is done at class diagram for static and sequence diagram for behavioral visualizations.
There is no state machine reverse engineering standard up to today therefore no tool has implemented this feature.

Comment: Hello, Thanks. However when I add code to the generated State Diagram at the hooks provided (actions etc), regeneration of the State Diagram successfully keep that code. Which of the current UML tools works gracefully in this area?

Comment: I have never seen a tool doing this state diagram reverse engineering. I must admit this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) comes with a Visual Execution Analysis tool set that has a number of outputs including Sequence Diagram generation of live code execution, State Transition Diagrams (sequence Diagram with states) as well as Profiler reports showing operation and call frequency.

I would suggest reading more on Enterprise Architect [Visual Execution Analysis](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/software_development/buildandrun.html) here.